# Linq to Entities subquery to fill array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

New at linq to entities trying to figure this out.  I have the following tables:

> `Customer: Cust_Id, Name`
>
> `Orders: Order_Id`
>
> `CustomerOrders: Cust_Id, Order_Id`

I have a class like so:

```
public class Customers
{
public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }

public Customers()
    {
        Rows = new List<Row>();
    }

    
    public class Row
    {
       public int Key { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public List<string> Order_Ids { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Linq query is like this:

```
var query = from c in context.Customer
select new Customers.Row
{
    Key = c.Cust_Id,
    Name = c.Name,
    Order_IDs = List<string>( ?? )
};

foreach (var row in query)
{
    Customers.Rows.Add(row);
}

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return serializer.Serialize(Customers);
```

Where I have '??', can I use a subquery or something to get a list of `Order_Id`'s from the `CustomerOrders` table?
Right Now, I can only think to loop through the `Customers` table once it is filled and then query the DB again to get each array of `Order Id`'s for each Customer.

Comment: `Customer.Rows.AddRange(--your LINQ query here --)` would be a shorter implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a requirement, drop the "Row" collection from the "Customer" object. This should suffice:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Order_Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can query like this:

```
var customers = from c in context.Customers
                select new Customer
                {
                    Key = c.Cust_Id,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Order_IDs = c.Orders.Select(o => o.Order_Id).ToList()
                };
```

It's better to deal in objects when writing C# and using EF, than to deal in terms of tables and rows -less confusing.

Comment: I had to change List<string> to List<int> because the Order_Id is int. However, I now get this error on the foreach line. Any ideas? LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: ToList() isn't translatable into an SQL command and therefore can't be used in a projection from a data context.  One option is to change Order_IDs in the Customer class to be an IEnumerable<int> instead of a List<int> and remove the ToList() if that will meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var query = from c in context.Customer
select new Customers.Row
{
    Key = c.Cust_Id,
    Name = c.Name,
    Order_Ids = c.Rows.Select(row => row.Key.ToString()).ToList()
};
```

Where you have `.Select(row => row.Key.ToString())` you can set the property you need (Key, Name, etc...). [Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) is an extension method to `IEnumerable` and it return a collection of type of property you have seted, in this case, a collection of strings because I converted it with `ToString()`  method.

Comment: Nice compact LINQ solution. You could also break out a full query like you have for Customers inline, or as a nested loop after all the Customers have been retrieved. With LINQ to Entities think of tables as arrays of objects and write your queries the same as you would write a code to select objects from those arrays.