# Enumeration Succeeds after DbContext Disposed

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**Background**

I am creating a projection from a parent/child relationship that includes a Name property of the parent and a list of the children's Ids.

**Code**

```
private class ParentChildInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> ChildIds { get; set; }
}

var infos = ctx.Masters.Include(m => m.Children).Select(
    m => new ParentChildInfo()
    {
        Name = m.Name,
        ChildIds = m.Children.Where(c => c.SomeProp.StartsWith("SpecialValue"))
                    .Select(c => c.Id).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Unfortunately that produced the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32]

That lead me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13810087/141172), which suggested ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13810301/141172)) making the following changes:

```
private class ParentChildInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> ChildIds { get; set; } // No longer List<int>
}

var infos = ctx.Masters.Include(m => m.Children).Select(
    m => new ParentChildInfo()
    {
        Name = m.Name,
        ChildIds = m.Children.Where(c => c.SomeProp.StartsWith("SpecialValue"))
                    .Select(c => c.Id) // Dropped the .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

I originally wanted to get lists rather than enumerables because the code that uses the result runs for several minutes, and I did not want to tie up the DbContext that long.

I use the code like this:

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
{
    // code from above that populates infoes
}

foreach (var info in infoes)
{
    // use info.ChildIds
}
```

I planned to move the `foreach` into the `using` so that I can enumerate the ChildIds, but hit F5 instead and was surprised to see that the code works.

**Question**

Given that the DbContext is disposed at that point and ChildIds is an `IEnumerable<int>` rather than `List<int>`, why exactly *can* I enumerate ChildIds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `ToList()` of the `infos` query actually executes the query. So the collection `ctx.Masters` is enumerated and the projections are populated. Even without the `Include` it would notice that `Master.Children` is addressed and emit the SQL join. The implementing type of `IEnumerable<int> ChildIds` is probably `List<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

You did .ToList() on the query so the query was executed and all the results are materialized and the connection to the database should be closed. I assume it would not work if you did not have .ToList() since (at least in EF5) the results are being processed in streaming fashion and entities are materialized when requested (i.e. on each iteration in the loop).